# ipywidgets working in JupyterLab but do not appear in Voila

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, voila, ipyleaflet

Ok, this is my first post.

I've been working on building a dashboard for my students, to let them work with economic models interactively. I've used JupyterLab for years and have some experience with ipywidgets. Recently while looking for a way to make my code shareable I ran into Voila, which seems like an excellent way to dashboard directly from a notebook.

Here's the problem I'm running into: I have widgets running just fine in JupyterLab but when I render them with Voila (both the extension and from the cli) the widgets do not appear. I tried using a few other packages: ipyleaflet does not appear either, but plotly and pandas printouts do.

I haven't been able to find similar cases so any help would be appreciated.

And for context, I'm running the latest version of JupyterLab on Zorin OS, and have reproduced the issue in Chrome and Firefox, with both Jupyter Lab and Notebook.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code example and a minimal virtual/conda environment? Often these rendering problems occur due to incompabilities between package versions.

Comment: Hi @above_c_level, it looks like your hunch was probably correct. I reinstalled python (ug) and everything's working now. Thanks!